# VLC 3: Adding file to existing playlist (enqueue)

Tags: playlist, vlc

VLC 2.x.x used to have the option `--playlist-enqueue` to add a file to the existing VLC Playlist. VLC 3.0.4 no longer has that option

```
$ vlc  --playlist-enqueue ~/Music/John_Mayer_Daughters.opus 
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
vlc: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `--playlist-enqueue'
Try `vlc --help' for more information.
```

Running `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC` with arguments will result in another instance of VLC being created.

```
$ vlc ~/Music/John_Mayer_Daughters.opus 
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
[00007fbacb531620] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00007fbacb500980] main libvlc error: interface "(null),none" initialization failed
[00007fbacb500980] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
```

There does not seem to be any setting for VLC to run in a single instance only.

[image: VLC Settings]

## Question

How can I:

1. Add a file into VLC's playlist from the command line?
2. Do the above without launching another instance of VLC?

Comment: The only answer you received is not very satisfactory and is certainly not platform-independent. I came here to ask the same question.

Comment: Props on using .opus!

Answer (score 3):

To add a file to VLC playlist from the command line (without starting a new instance) use the following syntax:

```
open -a /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC <your_media>
```

To prevent VLC from autoplaying the media you just added, go to `Preferences` > `Show all` > `Interface` > `Main Interfaces` > `macosx` and uncheck the box "Auto-playback of new items" below the Behavior subheading.

Comment: Note: this is using VLC version 3.0.8